# Channel error NoClassDefFoundError prior initialization failed

Tags: sap-pi

While upgrading SAP PI to newer version 7.5, I got this error:

> `A channel error occurred. The detailed error (if any) : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/mq/jms/MQQueueConnectionFactory : cannot initialize class because prior initialization attempt failed <br> at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) <br>`
>
> [image]

Can anyone tell where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As this is a JMS Channel it simply says it's missing classes from the driver library you are trying to use in your channel.
Make sure you have your adapter libs deployed that contain jars with the class described as missing there (com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory).